# asm volatile("pause") vs std::this_thread::yield()

Tags: c++, linux-kernel

Some relevant discussion: [Is std::this_thread::yield any different from sched_yield on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600135/is-stdthis-threadyield-any-different-from-sched-yield-on-linux)

I'm Wondering:

1. `this_thread::yield()` usually needs to switch from user mode to kernel mode
2. volatile pause still remains in user mode, but cpu pauses for ~30 clocks.

So, yield is more expensive than pause.

Wonder if the above understandings are correct?

I am trying to understand how `yield` and `pause` work internally.

Comment: `this_thread::yield()` gives up any remaining time-slice and waits for the OS to reschedule the thread. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37065332/3370124) _"...`_mm_pause` (the intrinsic for `pause`) won't release CPU for scheduler..."_

Comment: is yield() more expensive than mm_pause then?

Comment: Defined expensive as the 2 operations do different jobs.  One reschedules the thread the other pauses the thread but still holds onto the CPU resource (like a busy-wait).

Comment: An interesting issue. Not usually worrying about performance when I'm yielding a thread.